# Run 3 str_replace more efficiently

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

So I currently run the following code:

```
$current_link = get_author_posts_url($user_id,strtolower($user_info->user_login));
$current_link = str_replace(" ", "-", $current_link);
$current_link = str_replace(".-", "-", $current_link);
$current_link = str_replace("author", "authors", $current_link);
```

However I feel that this code could be more efficient. As I'm running str_replace 3 times on the same string.
So I used `preg_replace` to minimize the code like so:

```
$cLPatterns = array(' ', '.-');
$current_link = preg_replace($cLPatterns, '-', $current_link);
$current_link = str_replace("author", "authors", $current_link);
```

But is there a way to use the `str_replace("author", "authors", $current_link)` as part of `preg_replace`

How can I make this code the most efficient.

Cheers

Comment: str_replace takes arrays as arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arrays for the find and replace arguments with the `str_replace` method:

```
$current_link = str_replace(array(" ",".-","author"), array("-","-","authors"), $current_link);
```

Comment: Ahh ok yeah this is what I'm looking for, thanks @rtfm